# Content outside of the block

Tags: html, css

[image]

Does anyone know what is that white space on the bottom of my page and how to solve that problem? The bckgr image should be 100vh, but as you can see it is not. Why?

```
.content {
    width:100%;
    background: url(../img/Background.png) no-repeat center;
    background-size:cover;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Works fine here. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/z8ty2egx/). So... there must be something going on that is not covered by the CSS you posted. Can you create a [mcve]?